# Cópia de arquivos via SSH entre dois servidores remotos

Tags: linux, ssh, lado-do-servidor

Como copiar arquivos do servidor1 para o servidor2 via SSH com apenas uma linha de comando, sendo que eu não estou logado em nenhum deles?

Estou em uma 3º máquina. E tenho as credenciais de ambos.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso tranquilamente, basta usar o comando scp.

```
scp usuario1@host1:path/* usuario2@host2:path/*
```

Se a cópia for só de arquivos use o `/*` se tiver pasta use o `-r` no scp.

```
scp -r usuario1@host1:path usuario2@host2:path
```

Comment: NA MOSCA! Muito obrigado, cara!

Answer (score 0):

```
scp arquivo usuario@servidor:/home/usuario
```

Não rola?

Comment: Estou em uma máquina A. Quero copiar arquivos do servidorX para o servidorY. Não posso entrar em Y e logar em X de lá pra fazer uma transferência direta. Nem ao contrário.

Answer (score 0):

usa o scp;
Loga na máquina a e dela vc manda pra máquina b

http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Utilizando-o-comando-scp

$ scp /var/lib/arquivos root@192.168.100.1:/home/damasceno

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando o Linux e estiver em ambiente gráfico, abra o TERMINAL (Dependendo da Interface que estiver Ex.: Gnome, Kde, LXDE...), abra três abas e veja o conteúdo de origem/destino que você quer copiar.

Ou se estiver no Windows, utilize o [Putty](http://www.putty.nl).

Feito isso, execute o comando:

```
scp "nome do arquivo / diretório " "nome do usuário"@"endereço ip da máquina":/"destino"
```